# d3js force extending object for tooltip

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

Folks-

I've been trying to add tooltips to a viz based on Mike Bostock's "Mobile Patent Suits"

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

I extended the object from:

{source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit"}

to
  {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit", tooltip: "my comment here"}

added https://gist.github.com/milroc/2975255 d3 helper tooltip JS to the scripts

created a tooltip object:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "70")
.style("visibility", "hidden");
```

and called it:

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.name;}))
  .attr("r", 6)
  .call(force.drag);
```

which works fine, but if I change it to:

```
  .call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.tooltip;}))
```

I get "undefined". I've managed to add properties to d3 objects before, and call them as tooltips, with tree diagrams. I'm not sure what I need to do differently here.

Thanks,

Ralph

edit:

(Thanks to Lars, first!)

Trying to add a second set of tooltips, but it appears structure of object "links" rather than "nodes" makes it a toss-up as to whether rolling over a circle yields the "nameLabel" tooltip of the 'source' or 'target'

extended object:

```
{source: "First", target: "Second", type: "dependency", tooltip: "tip for rollover of path", nameLabel: "tip for rollover of circle"}
```

working path tooltip:

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
.call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.tooltip;}));
```

dodgy circle tooltip:

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.nameLabel;}))
.attr("r", 12)
.call(force.drag);
```

Now, the tooltip does recognize the circle, because this works:

```
.call(d3.helper.tooltip(function(d,i){return d.name;}))
```

so i built a function I thought I could pass the name to:

```
function whatTip(theName) {
var fullArray = new Array;
var fullArray = (("FIRST","first tooltip"),("SECOND","second tooltip"),("THIRD","THIRD tooltip"),("FIFTH","FIFTH tooltip"),("SIXTH","sixth tooltip"),("FOURTH","FOURTH tooltip") );
for(var i=0;i<fullArray.length;i++){
if (fullArray[i][0] == theName) {
return fullArray[i][1];
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well folks I figured it out:

What I ended up doing is adding two attributes: sourceTip and destTip (because some nodes are only destinations).

```
{source: "Forms", target: "AO/TOA", type: "dependency", tooltip: "Forms tooltip here", sourceTip: "Forms tip", destTip: "AO/TOA tip"},
```

then I created the nodes:

```
var mylinks = links.forEach(function(link){
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, tooltip: link.tooltip, nameTip: link.sourceTip});
link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, tooltip: link.tooltip, nameTip: link.destTip});
});
```

with the only trick being that I set the attribute "nameTip" to the sourceTip/destTip, for source and target, respectively.

That means I can call it from the tooltip using the nameTip attribute:

```
.append("svg:circle")
         .call(d3.helper.tooltip()
            .attr({class: function(d, i) { return d + ' ' +  i + ' A'; }})
            .style({color: '#a1d373'})
            .text(function(d, i){ return d.nameTip; })
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute when you're computing the nodes as well. Assuming that you're using the same code as in the example you've linked to, you need to change

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

to

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, tooltip: link.tooltip});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, tooltip: link.tooltip});
});
```

Comment: I am now trying to associate one type of tooltip with a "path", and another with a "circle". Calling the tooltip with d.name successfully yields the name of the circle, but I need a separate text string. I have added another object to the link object "circleTip", but when adding this as a mouseover event, it's associated with the link, rather than the circle.

I suppose this is due to how the object is created. I figure I need to either edit the tooltip helper or use a different method?

Comment: It all depends on the mouseover handler -- in the one that you attach to the paths, use the path tooltip and in the one you attach to the circles, use the circle tooltip.

Comment: how would I associate a tooltip ("nameLabel") with a circle? It appears I'm creating the links here:

`code`links.forEach(function(link) {
      `code`link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, tooltip: link.tooltip, nameLabel: link.nameLabel});
      `code`link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, tooltip: link.tooltip, nameLabel: link.nameLabel});
    `code`});


But it appears the nodes are created from the links. So when I hover over a circle, I get a tooltip associated with a link..

Comment: This code is where you're assembling the data structures. You're attaching the mouse handlers when the DOM elements are created. So you need to select the right tooltip when the respective DOM elements are created.

Comment: I get that- but the DOM elements are links, not circles. So it works great when I mouse over a link, because it knows I'm talking to a link. However, when I mouse over a circle, it could be the source of one link, or the target of another. Depending on what link was created last, mousing over a given circle yields the "nameLabel" associated with a source, or a target.

Comment: The DOM elements for your graph are circles (for the nodes) and paths (for the links). You are adding them both explicitly when you pass in `force.nodes()` and `force.links()` as data. In both cases you can attach a mouse handler that will have access to that data. It's in this data that you need to provide the information you want to show in the tooltip.

Comment: I get adding the mousehandlers see above my edited original question. I added the second mousehandler to the circle. I don't understand where I can 
1. add the second tooltip _in an array_ where it's associated with a node and not a link

2. loop through the nodes, and associate the tooltips with the nodes

Remember, the code I'm using distinctly says that it will "compute the distinct nodes from the links" (links.ForEach function)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I think the easiest way to fix this would be to iterate over the array of nodes after it has been created and add the tooltip you want to the respective nodes. Then you can reference it in the mouse handler the same way as for the links.

Comment: Lars- do you have any idea how to
1. properly iterate through the array of nodes
2. assign a variable text string to a new property?
thanks

Comment: You can do it in the same way you iterate over the links -- `nodes.forEach(...)` and then just assign the text to a property like `.tooltip`.

Comment: var myNodes = nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.circleTip = "test";});
 
yields the error "nodes.forEach is not a function"

Comment: links.forEach(function(node) {
   node.title = "test"; 
});

so I'm trying to get at it from links as well...

Comment: You need to iterate after you have populated `nodes` by iterating through the links.